# How to find corner coordinates of Image contour in Opencv and C

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have to find corner points of an image so that I can crop it in rectangular shape.I have already found the contour and used approxpoly() function  on it.Now how to find the corner Co-ordinates of the contour ? 
Here is my C code->

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
IplImage *img,*gray;

if((img = cvLoadImage("save.jpg", 1)) == NULL)
{
    printf("A Img open error\n");
}

gray=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvCvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

IplImage* out_median = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvSmooth( gray,out_median,CV_MEDIAN,3);

IplImage* out_threshold = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(out_median), out_median->depth, 1);
cvThreshold(out_median,out_threshold,1,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage();
CvSeq* first_contour = NULL;

cvFindContours(out_threshold,storage,&first_contour,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

CvSeq* approx_polygon = NULL;
approx_polygon=cvApproxPoly(first_contour,sizeof(CvContour),storage,CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,0.01*cvArcLength(first_contour,CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 1),0);

    //cvDrawContours(out_threshold,approx_polygon,cvScalarAll(255),cvScalarAll(255),100);
//cvShowImage("Contours", out_threshold );
//cvSaveImage("save_approxpoly_contour.jpg",out_threshold);


cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

This my Contour Image after applying the Approxpoly()
[image]

Comment: If you already have the contours, a simple math calc would reveal the points of the corner. Do a simple iteration on the points you have, looking for the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right points. There's no need to use an additional library for this. This is basic math calc, if I understood your problem right.

Comment: yea I know what you are talking about ,like for finding the bottom-rightmost coordinate of the contour ,the product should be maximum.
Can you tell me what function will give me the points so that can iterate them.Is there anything like contour->x/y or something like that to get the points.

Comment: http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/51631

Comment: `CvPoint pt = *(CvPoint*) cvGetSeqElement(contour, i);` This code line in the above message  was all ,that I needed.Thank You Abid.

Comment: That yahoo group link is dead or semi-dead, the group is closed and membership requires approval, can someone still access it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/):

Get the blobs:

```
cvThreshold(&src, &dst, 10, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
IplImage *labelImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&dst),IPL_DEPTH_LABEL,1);
CvBlobs blobs;
unsigned int result = cvLabel(&dst, labelImg, blobs);
```

If you have more than one item, find the limits

```
int borders[4];
borders[0] = 99999; //left
borders[1] = 99999; //top
borders[2] = 0;  //right
borders[3] = 0;  //bottom

for (CvBlobs::const_iterator it=blobs.begin(); it!=blobs.end(); ++it)
{   
    if((*it).second->maxx) < borders[0]){
        borders[0] = (*it).second->maxx; 
    }
    if(((*it).second->miny) < borders[1]){
        borders[1] = (*it).second->miny;
    }
    if((*it).second->minx) > borders[2]){
        borders[2] = (*it).second->minx;
    }
    if(((*it).second->maxy) > borders[3]){
        borders[3] = (*it).second->maxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Using just this code,will I able to get the corner points of the image ?

Comment: depends on what the original image is, if you threshold it right and the corner of the thresholded image is the corner you want, then yes. If the above image was the thresholded image, then you'd get the corner `(x,y)` by looking at `blobs[0].second->maxx` and `blobs[0].second->maxyy`